# Object not parallel

Tags: transforms

I want to modify the surface (the sole of the shoe). It is possible to parallelize the sole on the cube?

[image]

I share my file to understand what I mean.

[image]

Comment: Hello, could you please tell a bit more about what you mean by "parallelize the sole on the cube"? Do you mean that the sole must be flat? or on of its face must be parallel to the cube?

Comment: I would like to have the sole flat and parallel to the cube

Comment: (You can include images in posts .. done that for you.)  Do you want to deform the sole so it's entirely flat? (Real trainers aren't like that) ... rotate the shoe? Both?

Comment: in that case you can simply select the faces and SZ0?

Comment: @RobinBetts I know but I need flat because I need to create a printed 3D model!

Comment: @moonboots yes, I can try to do in this way

Comment: there are other ways but it's probably the easiest